# Separate MYSQL queries generate error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Quick SQL question... When I run the following queries, everything gets dumped to the first column of my DB (`1980`) ... When I am clearly specifying that the second query should apply to the second column of my DB (`1981`).. Any ideas before I start pulling my hair out? :-)

```
INSERT INTO `merit_order` (`1980`) VALUES ('2'), ('17'), ('10'), ('20'), ('9'), ('24'), ('33'), ('54'), ('5'), ('40'), ('12'), ('1'), ('6'), ('3'), ('18'), ('60'), ('72'), ('55'), ('63'), ('19'), ('44'), ('37'), ('35'), ('36'), ('30'), ('28'), ('25'), ('23'), ('4'), ('61'), ('8'), ('80'), ('49'), ('43'), ('53'), ('47'), ('45'), ('46'), ('48'), ('52'), ('42'), ('16'), ('22'), ('26'), ('14'), ('11'), ('27'), ('29'), ('31'), ('32'), ('13'), ('38'), ('39'), ('15'), ('41'), ('7'), ('21'), ('51'), ('50'), ('34'), ('57'), ('79'), ('81'), ('70'), ('68'), ('58'), ('62'), ('56'), ('76'), ('73'), ('74'), ('64'), ('65'), ('66'), ('71'), ('59');
INSERT INTO `merit_order` (`1981`) VALUES ('2'), ('17'), ('10'), ('20'), ('9'), ('24'), ('33'), ('54'), ('5'), ('40'), ('12'), ('1'), ('6'), ('3'), ('18'), ('60'), ('72'), ('55'), ('63'), ('19'), ('44'), ('37'), ('35'), ('36'), ('30'), ('28'), ('25'), ('23'), ('4'), ('61'), ('8'), ('80'), ('49'), ('43'), ('53'), ('47'), ('45'), ('46'), ('48'), ('52'), ('42'), ('16'), ('22'), ('26'), ('14'), ('11'), ('27'), ('29'), ('31'), ('32'), ('13'), ('38'), ('39'), ('15'), ('41'), ('7'), ('21'), ('51'), ('50'), ('34'), ('57'), ('79'), ('81'), ('70'), ('68'), ('58'), ('62'), ('56'), ('76'), ('73'), ('74'), ('64'), ('65'), ('66'), ('71'), ('59');
```

Further detail: for some reason that is too long to explain here, I must push the values column by column and not row by row. This is why I need to make separate queries for each column. As far as I know, this is the correct way to push values into columns (INSERT INTO TABLE (column) VALUES (a), (b), (c), etc....) which is what I am doing here..

Comment: The values are identical. Are you saying when you run these queries, each value is added to the 1980 column twice?

Comment: *huh?* `1980` is a column, not a DB. `INSERT INTO TABLE (col) VALUES (vars)`

Comment: Can you provide *what* you're attempting, and a your DB layout?

Comment: Yes, so all values are in the 1980 column. The ones that should be in 1981 are just pushed under the ones for 1980! Makes no sense to me (the values are identical, but that is just incidental here)

Comment: Can you provide full code including any PHP since it's tagged as so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two `INSERT` queries, that means you'd be creating **TWO** records. You'd end up with a table that looks like

```
1980   1981
2      null
17     null
10     null
etc...
null   2
null   17
null   10
```

If you want to fill in the `1981` column in the SAME records that you created with the first `insert`,you'd either have to run a separate `UPDATE` query to change each row's values, or do  both columns in ONE insert:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (`1980`, `1981`) VALUES ('2', '2'), ('17', '17'), etc...
```

or a LONG series of

```
 UPDATE yourtable SET `1981` = '2' WHERE `1980`= 2
 UPDATE yourtable SET `1981` = '10' WHERE `1980`= 10
 etc...
```

or even just

```
 UPDATE yorutable SET `1981` = `1980`.
```

Comment: Marc, your diagnosis is spot on -perfect :-) Is there no simple way I can just 'paste' the data column-wise? I don't need to match rows like in the example you have provided..

Comment: if both columns get the exact same value, then insert into one and do another update to copy the values over to the other one. the other option is to use a trigger to trap the inserts and do the copying there. but either way, you'll have the dupe the values, or copy them somehow

Comment: The columns don't have the same values, it is just a coincidence in my example that the values for 1980 and 1981 are the same.. Is there no way I can say 'start updating the rows from row 1' or something like that?

Comment: not really. mysql has no concept of row numbers, and doesn't support the windowing functions that other dbs have to give you row numbers.

Comment: Thanks Marc -have a nice one.

Comment: Marc -your comments have prompted another question, which I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449337/how-to-rank-column-values-for-mysql-database)