# Ranking column values in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am performing a ranking exercise for values in my database. Each column is a year and each has 76 values (i.e. 76 rows under each year). The years are from 1980 to 2035. My script must go through each year (column) in turn, and rank the values (i.e. arrange them in ascending order and then spit out the associated IDs).

I have written the script below, and it works, but it takes three seconds which I think is very slow. For the first column (1980) it's quick, as I can insert them in one go. For the others I cannot as I need to UPDATE the table and therefore match rows - which results in a separate SQL query for each value.

Is there a better way to do this? Here is my code:

```
for ($x = 1980; $x <= 2035; $x++) {
    $sql="SELECT `ID`,`$x` FROM marginal_costs ORDER BY `$x`";
    $concat = "";
    $counter = 1;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($x==1980) {
             $concat = $concat."('".$row['ID']."'), ";
        } else {   
             $upload="UPDATE `merit_order` SET `$x`='".$row['ID']."' WHERE `ID`='$counter';";
             echo $upload;
             mysqli_query($con, $upload);
             $counter= $counter + 1; 
        }
    }

    if($x==1980) {
        $concat = substr_replace($concat, "", -2).";";
        $upload="INSERT INTO `merit_order` (`$x`) VALUES $concat;";
        mysqli_query($con, $upload);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are executing a big query on the database, it's not weird that it's being slow O.o

Comment: plus having columns like that is not a very good design. why not just a generic "year" column? Don't treat the DB as if it was a spreadsheet.

Comment: I am not thankful for the downvote. The way I am doing it is clearly inefficient as am performing a ridiculous number of queries instead of doing a single large query. There must be a better way of doing it (perhaps by building an array). For the moment, this runs more slowly than say, a comparable script in excel.

Comment: So, basically you are asking why the script takes 3 seconds for executing 76 SELECT + 75 UPDATE + 1 INSERT Queries together?

Comment: I am building some kind of model that will require different years and multiple calculations -I am not sure I can achieve this with a single 'year' column. In each query I am careful to select only the columns I need.

Comment: J A, yes. I am also asking if there is a better way to achieve my objective :-)

Comment: Firstly, is your table indexed?

Comment: I think this can be efficiently achieved by EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model. How about you take a step back and append more information (regarding what you'd like to achieve) to your question? This place is full of talented people. I am sure someone would be able to point you to the right direction.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Wouldn't make a huge difference I believe, as 76 specific columns are being used in ORDER BY clause!

Comment: @JA Yeah, you're right. I think OP should rethink and go with what SQL was originally conceived as, in using the power of relative tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sends a lot of SQLs to your database generating unnecessary communication. This is one thing you could optimize... Two options:

- You write a stored procedure to do this whole thing, so you optimize a bit the communication, but you give some extra work to your db;
- Try to minimize the number of SQLs that you use: try to fetch data once (you construct a big select where you select everything, all the years); do the ranking in php; then construct a few updates (for instance for each id) and inserts, and send these to the db; and you are done :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I ended up implementing a solution very similar to the one suggested.